# What is the difference between try-catch and throws Exception in terms of performance?

Tags: java, performance, exception

I know that there are difference in terms of usage. But I would like to discuss about the performance difference.

BTW, there is a sentence in "Effective Java":

> Placing code inside a try-catch block inhibits certain optimizations that modern JVM implementations might otherwise perform.

So, if there is a method throwing Exceptions, does it means that such kind of optimization won't be applied to this method?

Comment: throws exception jumps you out of the try block and into the specific exception block that was thrown. Trys always need a catch and wlll usually have a default catch at the end of all of the other catches.

Comment: I knew that. It is the difference in terms of usage. I am trying to ask the performance difference. In a word: which one is faster?

Comment: Your question is flawed. It is code dependent. If I have a try catch block and I jump out of my try block during the first throw, it means there was an exception.and the rest of the code in my other exceptions/try will not be run. It's completely project dependent. The algorithmic runtime will only change based on how you implement the exceptions (meaning which one gets thrown first) or if it gets thrown at all.

Comment: I do not have deep knowledge of how JVM optimizes code. But adding `try-catch` blocks means adding code branches to the byte code (if something goes wrong between point A and point B in code, check the exception table to see if it has to be caught and then run the code pointed by the catch block). Branches naturally prevent optimizations since the compiler cannot reorder the code for better performance.

Comment: What would happened if we thrown the exception? Would the branches still be there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the paper, [Optimizing Java Programs in the Presence of Exceptions](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-45102-1_21):

> The Java language specification requires that exceptions be precise,
>   which implies that:
>
> 1. when an exception is thrown, the program state observable at the entry of the corresponding exception handler must be the same as in
>      the original program; and
> 2. exception(s) must be thrown in the same order as specified by the original (unoptimized) program.
>
> To satisfy the precise exception requirement, Java compilers disable
>   many important optimizations across instructions that may throw an
>   exception...This hampers a wide range of program optimizations such as
>   instruction scheduling, instruction selection, loop transformations,
>   and parallelization.

In presence of a `try-catch` block, JVM maintains an exception table. For each new catch block, the compiler will add an entry to the exception table. If an exception occurs, JVM needs to go through each entry in the table and check if the exception is defined in the exception table (this requires type analysis too). The result is a much more complex control structure which in turn will greatly hamper compiler optimization.

`throws` on the other hand, allows the exception to propagate. Although this might be better for performance, an uncaught exception can potentially crash the thread, the whole application, or even kill the JVM itself!

**How to decide when to use `try-catch`?**

I think correctness and reliability concerns play a more important role than performance here. But if you have only performance in mind, the authors in [this link](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/exceptional-performance/) have done extensive bench-marking for java code in presence of exceptions. Their most basic conclusion is that if you use exceptions for truly exceptional cases (not as a means for program flow control) there will not be much of a performance hit.

Answer (score 3):

Why not to try in code?

```
public class ExPerformanceTest {

    private int someVar = 0;
    private int iterations = 100000000;

    @Test
    public void throwTest() throws Exception {
        long t;
        t = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
            throwingMethod();
        }
        t = System.currentTimeMillis() - t;
        System.out.println("Throw Test took " + t + " ms");
    }

    @Test
    public void tryCatchTest() throws Exception {
        long t;
        t = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
            tryCatchMethod();
        }
        t = System.currentTimeMillis() - t;
        System.out.println("Try-Catch Test took " + t + " ms");
    }

    @Test
    public void anotherTryCatchTest() throws Exception {
        long t;
        t = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
            tryCatchMethodThatNeverEverThrows();
        }
        t = System.currentTimeMillis() - t;
        System.out.println("Try-Catch That Never Throws Test took " + t + " ms");
    }

    private void throwingMethod() throws Exception {
        // do some stuff here
        someVar++;
        willNeverThrow();
    }

    private void tryCatchMethod() {
        try {
            // do some stuff here
            someVar++;
            willNeverThrow();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("You shouldn't see this ever");
        }
    }

    private void tryCatchMethodThatNeverEverThrows() {
        try {
            // do some stuff here
            someVar++;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("You shouldn't see this ever");
        }
    }

    private void willNeverThrow() throws Exception {
        if (someVar == -1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Shouldn't happen");
        }
    }
}
```

That gives quite expected numbers:

Run 1

```
Try-Catch That Never Throws Test took 36 ms
Throw Test took 139 ms
Try-Catch Test took 160 ms
```

Run 2

```
Try-Catch That Never Throws Test took 26 ms
Throw Test took 109 ms
Try-Catch Test took 113 ms
```

Run 3

```
Try-Catch That Never Throws Test took 32 ms
Throw Test took 137 ms
Try-Catch Test took 194 ms
```

Obviously, JVM spotted that `tryCatchMethodThatNeverEverThrows` doesn't effectively need a `catch` part and optimized that, so the method execution took few times less, than others.

In other case, having a `catch` clause with handling takes some time indeed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the testing. It is quite interesting to see that Throw Test spent less time than Try-Catch Test. Can we conclude that throw Exception is faster than try-catch?

Comment: @Finch if you ignore rationale of handling exceptions, then probably yes. However, in some cases you may have `Try-Catch That Never Throws` situation and JVM will make it faster

Comment: I guess we missed one situation: throw that never throws.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code

```
public class Test {
static int value;

public void throwsTest(int i) throws Exception {
    value = ((value + i) / i) << 1;
    // if ((i & 0xFFFFFFF) == 1000000000) {

    // }
    if ((i & 0x1) == 1) {
        throw new Exception();
    }

}

public void tryAndCatchTest(int i) {
    value = ((value + i) / i) << 1;

    try {
        // if ((i & 0xFFFFFFF) == 1000000000) {

        // }
        if ((i & 0x1) == 1) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int i;
    long l;
    Test t = new Test();

    l = System.currentTimeMillis();
    value = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < 10000000; i++) {
        try {
            t.throwsTest(i);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
    l = System.currentTimeMillis() - l;
    System.out.println("Throws: " + l + " ms");
    i = 0;
    l = 0;
    l = System.currentTimeMillis();
    value = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < 10000000; i++) {
        try {
            t.tryAndCatchTest(i);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
    l = System.currentTimeMillis() - l;
    System.out.println("Try and catch: " + l + " ms");

}
```

}

After testing the response time was sometimes faster with the throws and sometimes try and catch. I tried this with throwing errors and just processing the statements. So, in conclusion, they are both equally efficient.

Example results with throwing exceptions:
Throws: 6802 ms
Try and catch: 6586 ms

Example results without:
Throws: 68 ms
Try and catch: 72 ms

I didn't account for running with code in the catch statement beings that if you're using a try and catch statement you need to run that code anyways and you wouldn't be throwing the exception.